# Looking for a regex to remove "print 'Processed 100 total records'" from a file

Tags: regex, vi

I'm looking for a VI regex that will search/replace all instances of the following text:

> print 'Processed 100 total records'

What is in between the quotes doesn't matter (it will change from 100, 200, 300, etc.).  Specifically I'm trying to match "print" followed by a space, and any text in single quotes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried the following, and some variations, to no avail:

> %s/print\s\'[0-9A-Za-z\s]+\'/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change a couple of things in your expression, it works for me:

```
%s/print\s'[0-9A-Za-z ]\+'/
```

Note the replacement of `\s` with a literal space in the set. I don't think you can use those keywords within there. Also, I had to add a backslash before the `+` to make it work. I guess you have to escape it!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
%s/print '.*'//g
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Worked like a charm